# How to make vm boot from live cd

Tags: boot, 13.04, cd, virtualization, fedora

I have created a vm for ubuntu 13.04 and configured it to boot from live CD (I want to try Fedora on it), but it doesn't boot. It displays a shell terminal I think and this is it.

Answer (score 10):

The method in AliNa answer if you have VirtualBox, but if you have VMWare Workstation, right click on the VM, choose Power, and then Power On to BIOS.  Once you get the BIOS screen, go to the Boot Tab, and change the Boot order, save and exit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Power On to BIOS is disabled!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Do you have VMware tools installed?

Comment: Yes. when I press F12 to see boot priority, I get this error: Could not start boot splash because can't access needed shared library

Comment: What are you trying to boot? What has changed?

Comment: I just want to repartition /dev/sda1. That used 100%. So removed some of my files and used storage became 89%, but I wanted more free space, so I increased whole hard storage from vmware menu, now should repartition. But can't boot from ISO!

Answer (score 6):

Run Oracle VM Virtualbox, select the virtual machine (if you have more than one) and open **Settings**.

Under the **System** portion of Settings you will see the **Boot order**, as in the below screenshot:

[image: VM Settings]

If you want to boot from an **.ISO** file, pause the VM on startup with <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Host key is Right Ctrl by default) and browse for the file on **Devices** > **CD/DVD Devices** > **Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file**. Then resume it again by the same key combination. It will boot from the ISO file.

Comment: You can also start the vm and hit F12 to select boot order

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more method for those of us configuring VMs on headless servers.

You'll need to know your storage controller's name and the port index of the dvd drive (usually 0). You can get that info from `showvminfo`.

```
vboxmanage storageattach MyVm --storagectl MyVm_sata --port 0 --type dvddrive --medium ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Launch the VM and then attach to it with an RDP client. If you do not have VRDP enabled you can do so with:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm MyVm --vrde on --vrdeport 5001
```

When you're done, remove the medium:

```
vboxmanage storageattach MyVm --storagectl MyVm_sata --port 0 --type dvddrive --medium none
```